Can one connect 2 or more DC motors of same or different excitations in series or parallel combination,and how does it work
I am trying to understand DC motors,but i had this doubt throughout the machines course. .How does speed and torques and speed gets affected(major query)

Do you mean series or parallel on the input or output side?

Ideal DC permanent magnet (PMDC) motors run at a speed proportional to voltage, and with a torque proportional to current. For non-ideal motors, preface 'proportional' with 'approximately'.
This means that identical PMDC motors in parallel will run at roughly the same speed. This is ideal if you have a 'motor per wheel' for a vehicle for instance. Each will draw sufficient current from the supply for its own torque requirements, so even loading one side of the vehicle more than the other will only result in a small speed difference.
Identical PMDC motors in series will run with the same torque. The sum of their speeds will be governed by the power supply voltage. This can result in some interesting behaviour. If you stall one motor, then the other will run at full speed. The torque you need to hold one motor stationary will reflect the torque that the running motor is delivering, though this is not all that useful to measure torque as it's cheaper and simpler to use an ammeter to measure the current.
If two (or more) motors are fixed to the same output shaft and so forced to run at the same speed, then switching between a series and parallel connection will give you a limited 'electronic gearing' back to your power supply.
Your question mentions 'excitation'. It's not clear whether this applies to a wound field motor, or PMDC motors with different field strengths. In all cases, the 'excitation' controls the constant of proportionality between speed/voltage, and current/torque. With wound field motors, shunt motors in series will more tricky to describe the behaviour than the other three configurations.

Parallel combinations will work as long as the power source can provide enough current. You need to be careful with this as there is a large surge current on startup and the  power source needs to be able to provide this.
Series combinations will be much more complex and should be avoided. A highly loaded motor wants a lot of current and if it is in series with a lightly loaded motor running at high speed which appears as a higher resistance its available torque will be reduced.
